# TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict() in heapq

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap

I am porting over code that works on python2. While porting it over I get error `unorderable types: dict() < dict()` on the following line

```
heapq.heappush(colors, color) #this throws error
return heapq.nsmallest(count, colors, key=lambda k: k['shade'])
```

These are the types:

```
`colors` is a <class 'list'>
`color` is a <class 'dict'>
```

How can I make this work in python3?

Comment: On what basis do you expect this comparison to function?

Comment: Can you provide examples for `colors` and `color`?

Comment: its pushing `color` class to the `colors` list and then finding the smallest based on `shade`. `shade` would be a number

Comment: You want what, then? The smallest key? If you showed example data, and described the output you expected given that data, it would be helpful.

Comment: To rephrase the question I asked earlier: On what basis is one dictionary "smaller than" another? How do you expect Python to make that determination?

Comment: @Anthony: Asking here, since you've deleted your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028023/how-to-revert-a-forced-push-in-gitlab). Did you manage to solve the problem? Or did one of your colleagues have a current `master` ready? (That being said, talk to your GitLab administrator about daily or weekly backups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `heapppush` here at all, because `nsmallest` already handles the heap ordering. It internally creates a heap and pushes items on it. `nsmallest` itself won't need the dicts to be orderable, because you specified the `key` parameter.

Just replace the heappush call with `colors.append(color)`.

Note that although your code worked in Python 2, all it did was rearrange the `colors` list in an arbitrary order before calling `nsmallest`.

Comment: So even in python2 calling `heappush` isn't needed ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want dictionaries to be orderable, you can't use the regular type. You can, however, use (immutable) `frozendict`s. See https://github.com/slezica/python-frozendict

Put only `frozendict`s into your list, and all should work properly.